Any MacOS equivalent to -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections?
On Linux and other systems, gcc and clang, when given -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections will essentially remove useless (unreferred to) functions from the target file. Is there any way to get this behavior under MacOS? (-ffunction-sections is silently ignored under MacOS)

The equivalent seems to be -Wl,-dead_strip.
